# How to customize angular material components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im completly new to programming.
I wanted to make a website and a friend told me Angular is nice and that I should use Angular Materials. But I dont like the looks of the components. How do I change the (S)CSS of the Components?
Thanks to everyone

Ive already tried Ng Deep it somehow doesnt work.
I also read something about view encapsolation but I didnt understand it

Because I dont know how to do customize anything in the component I first tried to just change the color of it but it didnt work with this code. I just put everything to red so I can see the difference.

app.component.html

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>
```

styles.scss

```scss
::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
  .mat-input-element {
    color: red;
  }    .mat-form-field-label {
         color: red;
       }    .mat-form-field-underline {
              background-color: red;
            }
  .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .mat-form-field-required-marker {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gipfeli, Please share some code on what have you tried so far or best you can create minimal reproducible https://stackblitz.com/ demo to help us understand better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the looks of Angular material, one way to do it is to add some specific classes in your global `style.scss` (the top level style.scss, not the one in the Components)

But it's highly discouraged to change the style of Angular Material!!!

It's a pain in the ass and also in future they might change some components or some classes, this could brake your changes and all your hard work will be for nothing.

Angular Material follows the Material Design, if you don't like it, don't use it!

You have two options: Use Angular CDK (which is kinda only a skeleton of the component with no style) and you have to write all the style, or the other option is to look for another UI library that you actually like, and use that instead.

Comment: Angular CDK is may be a good option...

Comment: yeah i think im going to go with cdk. do you know where to start?

Comment: honestly I never used CDK without material. I think don't need any special setup. I guess you can just install it and start using it following the documentation:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories

since you are new to Angular I would start with the basic and focus on CDK later. Getting started tutorials: https://angular.dev/tutorials